# Read a whole XML line and save it into an array? JDOM

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I have a very simple question, yet i cant solve it, I hope you can help me.

How can I read a whole line of an XML file with JDOM? I need the Tag and the attribute and want to save it in one array. How can I do this?

```
    package converter;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter;

import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.input.*;
import org.jdom2.output.*;

public class Converter {

    public List<Entry> xmlconvert(String pfad, String pfad2, String bitmask){
        List<Entry> entry = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        List<Entry> wrongEntries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        String wrongEntryIndexes = "";

        String[] languages = {"en", "pt", "it", "fr", "es", "de", "zh"};

        try{


        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.build(pfad);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Converting successful.");
        return entry;
```

As you can see, its just the beginning >.<

For the CSV File i did it like that:

```
public List<Entry> convert(String pfad, String pfad2, String bitmask) {

    List<Entry> entry = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    List<Entry> wrongEntries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    String wrongEntryIndexes = "";

    String[] languages = {"en", "pt", "it", "fr", "es", "de", "zh"};

    try {

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(pfad), ';', '\"', 1);

        String [] nextLine;

        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            Entry entryi = new Entry();
            entryi = new Entry();
            entryi.termEntryID = nextLine[0];
            entryi.termEntryUUID = nextLine[1];
            entryi.termID = nextLine[2];
            entryi.termUUID = nextLine[3];
            entryi.term = nextLine[4];
            entryi.status = nextLine[5];
            entryi.language = nextLine[6];
            entryi.domains = nextLine[7];
            entryi.morphosyntacticRestriction = nextLine[8];
            entryi.variantsConfiguration = nextLine[9];
            entryi.isHeadTerm = nextLine[10];
            entryi.checkInflections = nextLine[11];
            entryi.frequency = nextLine[12];
            entryi.createdBy = nextLine[13];
            entryi.createdOn = nextLine[14];
            entryi.changedBy = nextLine[15];
            entryi.changedOn = nextLine[16];
            entryi.context = nextLine[17];
            entryi.crossReference = nextLine[18];
            entryi.definitionDE = nextLine[19];
            entryi.definitionEN = nextLine[20];
            entryi.example = nextLine[21];
            entryi.externalCrossReference = nextLine[22];
            entryi.gender = nextLine[23];
            entryi.geographicalUsage = nextLine[24];
            entryi.imageURL = nextLine[25];
            entryi.note = nextLine[26];
            entryi.numerus = nextLine[27];
            entryi.partOfSpeech = nextLine[28];
            entryi.processStatus = nextLine[29];
            entryi.sourceOfDefinition = nextLine[30];
            entryi.sourceOfTerm = nextLine[31];
            entryi.termType = nextLine[32];
            entry.add(entryi);
        }
```

But for the CSV file is it easy to write it again in the same structure. I saved all variables in different arrays and then i check them.

Comment: If you have tried anything please show us.

Comment: @Jagson, DIY. _PS_:why do you want to store Tag and attribute in one array? and what about the value of attribute and text/node value?

Comment: Actually not, im trying to build a converter for XML files. The Converter should search for some parameters, delete them, and then multiplying the entry with other 7 different parameters. Now im thinking about it how I can do it for best results. I actually have the program for CSV files. But now im really confused how i can do the same with XML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is hard to say without knowing the structure of your XML but according to your comments I guess you have something like this:

```
<parentElement>
    <childElement>
        <attr1>XXX</attr1>
        ....
    </childElement>
   ... more childElements
</parentElement>
```

You already have the Document so you need to iterate through the childElement tags. For that:

```
Element root = doc.getRootElement();
List<Element> childElements = root.getChildren("childElement");
```

And just iterate through the childElements

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about XML you should not talk about lines, only the start and end tags matter. Lines have no meaning in XML, except for human readability. If you have got the wanted `Element`-instance you can call `getName()` and `getAttributes()` to collect all you information. You could then push them onto any kind of `List` and covert it into a `String[]` afterwards.

This does however not make very much sense, because XML in general has a tree structure and you are trying to force it into a flat structure. Moreover, if you want a flat structure look at a `Map` or a `Set`, then you can save the key (name of element or attribute) and the value as one pair.

Maybe some XML example showing the gernal schema of your files and the code you use to read the XML so far would be of use.

Comment: Ah that sounds good! But how can I actually rewrite the saved information in the same structure i readed it from the original file?

Comment: Can you edit that into your main question. That will make it easier for people to help you :-)

Comment: Other Question. My XML file is very big. There are always the same parts which popup over and over again. Can i Scan and save every Element, Child and Attribute of the Child? Then go to the next line and save it again? At the same time, the structure must be safed too.